# How to enable/disable ToolStripMenuItem dynamically based on database user info?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I have 2 forms. One is login form, one is a workspace form (set as mdi Container with `ToolStripMenuItem` controls).

```
workspace form = f1
login form = f2
```

My application works by first loading f1, then loading f2 at the same time. my code for loading f2 during f1 loading is as below:

```
Dim uLogin As New frm2
'set the parent form of child window
uLogin.MdiParent = Me
uLogin.Show()
```

After the correct password and userid, f2 should be unloaded, enter the workspace and disable the menu items based on user table:

```
'i have put this piece of code after success login function
Dim dr As Datarow
Dim userDS As Dataset
Dim userDT As Datatable
userDS = some sql db query
userDT = userDS.Tables(0)
If userDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    dr = userDT.Rows(0)
End If

For Each dr In userDT.Rows

    Dim ParentMenu As New  ToolStripMenuItem(dr.Item("MI_MenuName").ToString)
    ParentMenu.Enabled = CBool(dr.Item("RR_menuIsEnabled"))

Next dr
```

This is the sample DB user table:

[image: This is the sample db user table]

My application UX:

[image: My application UX]

There is no error, the user logged in, but the enabling/disabling of menu items doesn't work as expected. Query TSQL is correct and am using VS 2005 and MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main MenuStrip is called "MenuStrip1", and its Modifiers() property has been changed to Public, you can use code like this:

```
Dim f1 As frm1 = DirectCast(Me.MdiParent, frm1)
For Each dr In userDT.Rows
    Dim mnuName As String = dr.Item("MI_MenuName").ToString()
    Dim mnus() As ToolStripMenuItem = f1.MenuStrip1.Items.Find(mnuName, True)
    If mnus.Length > 0 Then
        mnus(0).Enabled = CBool(dr.Item("RR_menuIsEnabled"))
    End If
Next dr
```

Comment: Hi,thanks. It's correct that my main menu strip is called MenuStrip1. But there is still an error: Name 'MenuStrip1' is not declared

Comment: You must be trying to use this code **outside** of the Form?  If so, you need to pass either a reference to the Form or the MenuStrip to where you're attempting to access it from.  Give me more details about your setup...

Comment: So is the code running in the MdiChild called "frm2"?

Comment: Yes. frm2 is the login form where I prompt user for userid and password. Once they are correct, frm2 will be closed and frm1 (which is the mdi container) will keep on activated (open).

Comment: Okay. Select MenuStrip1 and change its Modifiers() property to Public.  Then the edited code above should work.

Comment: Done it, but still an error: 'FirstOrDefault' is not a member of 'System.Array'. is it because I didn't use an array (list) to store the menu name from the query?